# Having trouble with sticky footer layout

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a site layout with a sticky footer and a header that go the width of the page. The content div should be 960px wide, and the height should go from the bottom of the header to the top of the footer. It should always be at least this height. Te problem i am facing right now is that I can get the content div to either be the height of it's contents or it expands past the wrap div, below where the page should end.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <style>
html{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}

body{
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
}

#wrap{
height:auto;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
margin:auto;
}

#header{
background: blue;
height: 152px;
}

#content{
background: #555;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;

}

#footer{
margin-bottom: 41px;
height: 59px;
background: red;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id ='wrap'>
        <div id='header'>
        </div>
        <div id='content'>
        </div>
        <div id='footer'>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i don't get what you mean, you might want to explain it clearer or it's just me not understanding it.

Comment: This is how the above code looks: 
[link](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/8005/layout1qo.png)

This is how it should look:
[link](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/6369/layout2sp.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `position:relative` for all you elements under #wrap, so they will position relatively under each other, and setting height to 100% is not helpful.

You have set footer position to absolute, that would make it stick to top of the page

Comment: The footer is set at absolute. Either way, this doesn't get my content div to span the vertical space between the footer and header